# Python Selenium Chrome Webdriver: interacti with a game

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver

I have got a problem with interacting with a website. For me, it's the first time I used Python for doing such a thing. I want to write a code in order to play the game in this link: https://www.coolmathgames.com/0-worlds-hardest-game.
I tried using this code to move the player inside the game, but the result is that the web page scrolls and the player doesn't move.

```
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.coolmathgames.com/0-worlds-hardest-game')

moves = [Keys.LEFT, Keys.DOWN, Keys.RIGHT, Keys.UP]
time.sleep(10)
i = 0
while i < 100:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html').send_keys(random.choice(moves))
    i += 1
```

(The time.sleep(10) instruction is inserted in order to allow me to manually enter in the game)

Which is the code to use to interact with the game and not only with the website page?

Comment: Check the answer below. That's what you need to do. Technical issues may occur since it's a platform with its special attributes and elements, but the logic in order to interact with the game is the one in the answer below. Hope that I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

The game is inside an iframe. You have to enter into the iframe and manipulate iframe's instances accordingly.

Check the following screenshot that I took from the link you inserted into your question:

[image]

Here is an example of how you can enter the iframe:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

## Enter into the iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

# Locate and do whatever you want inside the iframe (all the tags or attributes must be sub-attributes of this iframe tag)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/p")

# If you don't want to do anything else inside the iframe and you want to do something in the platform (outside of the game) then you need to quit from the iframe and switch to the default content by executing the following line
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

If you need anything else in detail check the official documentation of [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/).